# Toggle with a click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have a small click function inside my website

```
$("#item").click(function() {
    $(".menu").addClass("active");
    $(".footer").removeClass("status");
});
```

Now when a user clicks on the #item - everything works, but now I would like to have the ability to inverse that, when the user clicks again on it, like so:

```
$(".menu").removeClass("active");
$(".footer").addClass("status");
```

And the user can click as much as he likes to do so. How is this possible?
I tried it with another click() inside the first click() but then it only works one time.

Comment: so use `toggleClass()`

Comment: Adding reference to [toggleClass()](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#item").click(function() {
    if(!$(".menu").hasClass("active")){
        $(".menu").addClass("active");
        $(".footer").removeClass("status");
    }else{
        $(".menu").removeClass("active");
        $(".footer").addClass("status");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`toggleClass`](https://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Ref:

> Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of
>   matched elements, depending on either the class's presence or the
>   value of the switch argument.

Code:

```
$("#item").click(function() {
    $(".menu").toggleClass("active");
    $(".footer").toggleClass("status");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This code may work

```
$("#item").click(function() {
       $(".menu").toggleClass("active");
       $(".footer").toggleClass("status");
});
```

but make sure you have correct classes applied before click event is fired.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#item").click(function()
{
    if($(".menu").hasClass("active"))
    {
        $(".menu").removeClass("active");
        $(".footer").addClass("status");
    }
    else
    {
        $(".menu").addClass("active");
        $(".footer").removeClass("status");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
$("#item").click(function() {
    var menu = $(".menu")
        , footer = $(".footer");

    if (menu.hasClass("active") && !footer.hasClass("status")) {
        menu.removeClass("active");
        footer.addClass("status");
    }
    else {
        menu.addClass("active");
        footer.removeClass("status");
    }
});
```